# GKE - expose service with Ingress and Internal Load Balancing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, url-rewriting, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I have REST API Web service on Internal GKE cluster which I would like to expose with internal HTTP load balancing.

Let's call this service "blue" service:
I would like to expose it in following mapping:

```
http://api.xxx.yyy.internal/blue/isalive -> http://blue-service/isalive
http://api.xxx.yyy.internal/blue/v1/get -> http://blue-service/v1/get
http://api.xxx.yyy.internal/blue/v1/create -> http://blue-service/v1/create
http://api.xxx.yyy.internal/ -> http://blue-service/ (expose Swagger)
```

I'm omitting deployment yaml, since it's less relevant to discussion.

But my service yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blue-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: blue-service
```

My Ingress configuration is the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: blue-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.xxx.yyy.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /blue/*
        backend:
          serviceName: blue-service
          servicePort: 80
```

However, I'm receiving 404 for all requests. `/blue/v1/get`, `/blue/v1/create` and `/blue/isalive` returns 404.

In my "blue" application I log all my notFound requests and I can clearly see that my URIs are not being rewritten, the requests hitting the application are `/blue/v1/get`, `/blue/v1/create` and `/blue/isalive`.

What am I missing in Ingress configuration? How can I fix those rewrites?

Comment: Your rewrite target can't work, considering you're not catching any expression in the `spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path`. See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target

Comment: If I change path to be ''/blue(/|$)(.*)", I receive the following from Load Balancer:  Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource': '{ "name": "k8s2-um-a0tq0oxi-default-blue-ingress-w0chp90v", "hostRule": [{ "host": ["api.putin....'. Invalid path pattern, invalid

Comment: The GCE ingress controller does not support the rewrite annotation ( see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109 ).  You can install the nginx ingress controller which does support this.  In the future, you should also be able to use the new Gateway controller (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api ) which is currently in preview.

Comment: You can also install Istio or Anthos Service Mesh and use Istio VirtualService resources as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem and writing it here to memo it and hopefully someone will find it as useful.

- First problem is that I have mixed annotations types. one of GKE ingress controller and second for Nginx Server controller. Currently GKE ingress controller doesn't support URL rewrite feature, so I need to use nginx ingress controller.
- so I need to install Nginx based ingress controller. It cloud be done easily using Helm chart or or deployment yaml. However, by default this controller will expose ingress using external load balancer and this not what I want. So we need to modify deployment charts or YAML file of this controller.
  I'm not using Helm, so I downoaded yaml itself using wget command.

```
    wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Open it in editor and find the definition of Service names `ingress-nginx-controller` in namespace `ingress-nginx`. Add the following annotation.

```
cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

After it I can run `kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml` command which will create Ingress controller for me. It will take a few minutes to provision it.

- In addition I need to open firewall rule which will allow master nodes access worker nodes on port `8443/tcp`.
- And the last item is an ingress yaml itself which should look like this:

  ```
   apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     annotations:
       nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
     name: blue-ingress
     namespace: default
   spec:
     rules:
     - host: api.xxx.yyy.internal
       http:
         paths:
         - backend:
             serviceName: blue-service
             servicePort: 80
           path: /blue(/|$)(.*)
  ```